# I cant edit(splice) a specific index in my array through DOM, using a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, dom

So i would like to change a specific index for eg "Lisa", and i want to do this through my DOM that i've created. As you can see i'm using a loop to get each `<tr>` and `<td>` out as a table. What im also doing is giving each of them an `id='edit"+[i]+"'` i've tried to combine each array with each id since they're always looping together.

````
var people = ["Olle", "Lisa", "Kalle", "Elin", "Johan", "Linda"];```

function listNames(){

  varMyinnerHTLM = "<table class='nametable table table-dark table-hover'>";
  varMyinnerHTLM += "<tbody>";
  varMyinnerHTLM += "<tr><th>Namn</th></tr>";

    for(i=0;i<people.length;i++){ //Loopar ut arrayens namn som en lista.
      varMyinnerHTLM += "<tr><td><a href='#'>"+people[i]+"</a><button type='button' id='edit"+[i]+"' class='close' aria-label='Close'onClick='edit()'><span aria-hidden='true'>&#x270f;</span></button><button id='close"+[i]+"' type='button' class='close' aria-label='Close' onClick='removeRow()'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></td></tr>";

    }

  varMyinnerHTLM + "</tbody>";
  varMyinnerHTLM += "</table>";
  varMyinnerHTLM += "<input type='text' id='newname' class='nameinput input-group-text' placeholder='Namnet på personen'></br>";
  varMyinnerHTLM += "<button type='button' id='addName' class='btn btn-primary' onClick='addName()'>Lägg till</button>";
  varMyinnerHTLM += "<button type='button' id='reset' class='btn btn-light' onClick='reset()'>Nollställ</button>";
  varMyinnerHTLM += "<button type='button' class='hide btn btn-success' onClick=''>Godkän</button>";
  document.getElementById("jspage").innerHTML = varMyinnerHTLM;


}
````

So what im trying to achieve is that i want to be able to edit a specific index in my array through a `onClick = "function()"` type of way. The value has to be given in the input and then the function `edit()` will continue with the following down below:

```
var fullid = people[i] + edit[i]
function edit(){
    nameValue = document.getElementById('newname').value;
    if(nameValue === ""){
      $('.nameinput').attr('style', "border-raidus: 5px; border:#C21414 1px solid;");
      $('#newname').attr('placeholder', "Ange nytt namn").placeholder();
    }else{
        people.splice(fullid, 1, nameValue);
        return listNames();
    }
}
```

Maybe its obvious or not, but i think my `people.splice(fullid, 1, nameValue);` is way wrong but might be wrong. Because at the moment it only edits the first index of my array which is `Olle` when i want to edit `Lisa` eg.

I hope it was clear enough to understand my motives. I'd like to solve it in javascript but it also works if its with jquery.

Comment: What is `people[i] + edit[i]` supposed to be? Where is the `i` variable? And `edit` is a function, not an array.

Comment: `spilce` uses index as first argument, don't think you are doing it.

Comment: Apologies if this is abit confusing, first time beeing on here. 

The ```people[i] + edit[i]``` is a poor approach of me trying to combine every index in the ```var people``` with each ```id='edit"+[i]+"'``` in my dom.

i want the ```function edit()``` to know which index its supposed to edit, but i cant seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `edit()` function so it takes the array index as a parameter. And there's no need to use `splice()` if you're just changing 1 element, just assign to the array index.

```
function edit(i){
    nameValue = document.getElementById('newname').value;
    if(nameValue === ""){
      $('.nameinput').attr('style', "border-raidus: 5px; border:#C21414 1px solid;");
      $('#newname').attr('placeholder', "Ange nytt namn").placeholder();
    }else{
        people[i] = nameValue;
        listNames();
    }
}
```

Then change the HTML so you pass `i` as an argument to the function.

```
      varMyinnerHTLM += "<tr><td><a href='#'>"+people[i]+"</a><button type='button' id='edit"+[i]+"' class='close' aria-label='Close'onClick='edit(" + i + ")'><span aria-hidden='true'>&#x270f;</span></button><button id='close"+[i]+"' type='button' class='close' aria-label='Close' onClick='removeRow()'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></td></tr>";
```

I'm not sure why you're returning something from `edit()`, the return value isn't used for anything. And `listNames()` doesn't return anything. Just call `listNames()` without using `return`.